# Why is my IntelliJ IDEA project not finding this import?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle, import

Trying to follow the guide here https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch

Here is my Gradle file

```
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')
}
```

And just for context, a screen of my project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8aqE.png

For some reason when I hit build, it seems to work fine, but for whatever reason it isn't able to find the `org.springframework` files such as the imports in this file:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Open the Gradle tab (should be on the right hand side of the window) and refresh your dependencies.

Comment: I do not see a Gradle tab

Comment: Nevermind, View ->Tool Windows -> Gradle got me the window, hit refresh. Seems to work now! Thanks! Do I have to do that every time I change my gradle? In Android Studio I'm used to Build taking care of everything, I guess it's different here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you refreshed Gradle project in your IDEA?

[image]

When you do so you should be able to see all required dependencies in "External Libraries" list.

[image]

EDIT: for some reason your IDEA may not have Gradle configured correctly. You can check in **File** -> **Settings...** -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Build Tools** -> **Gradle** if your project is linked correctly with Gradle:

[image]

You can mark "Use auto-import" if you want to make Gradle import automatically all dependencies for you. The only problem is that it may consume a lot of resources and make your IDE run slowly. It may not sound like a convenient solution, but refreshing project manually when it is needed works better I think.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, looks it looks ok

Comment: Is it normal to use the gradle toolbar refresh window when changing dependencies or do most people use it similar to how I use Android Studio? (hit Build and everything else just seems to work / import / etc)

Comment: You can mark "Use auto-import" if you want to make Gradle import automatically all dependencies for you. The only problem is that it may consume a lot of resources and make your IDE run slowly. It may not sound like a convenient solution, but refreshing project manually when it is needed works better I think.

Comment: When you say IDE run slowly, do you mean just during the build process, or permanently, etc?

Comment: I had it marked once a few years ago - any small change in build.gradle (or related) files forced Gradle to refresh dependencies and it was making my IDEA running very slowly. I haven't tested auto-import since then, I just got used to manual import every time I add/modify dependency in build.gradle file :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add maven dependency spring-web

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
<version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.1.5.RELEASE